# Java не передает string по сокету в qt

Tags: java, c++, qt, сокет, tcp

Хочу отправить строку из java приложения в qt приложение.

```
public static OutputStreamWriter writeSockQt = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket3.getOutputStream());)
```

Код Java для отправки сообщения:

```
            System.out.println("Closer: write mes in Qt");
            
            String mesForQt = "killProcess\r\n"; //Сообщение для Qt
            
            writeSockQt.write(mesForQt); //Отправка сообщения в Qt
            writeSockQt.flush(); //Протолкнуть данные
```

---

Принятие сообщения в qt:
сделал слот:

```
    connect(socketMessage, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(sockMesReady()));
```

Код слота:

```
qDebug() << "sendJava::sockMesReady "
                "Получение данных от java";

    if(socketMessage->waitForConnected(500))
    {
        socketMessage->waitForReadyRead(500);

        mesRes = socketMessage->readAll();
        if(mesRes != ""){

            qDebug() << mesRes;

            isClose = true;
            
        }
    }
```

Если получилось принять в qt то, что задумывалось, я меняю глобальную переменную isClose на значение true.
При дебаге не срабатывает мой созданный connect сигнала и слота. И я даже не захожу в этот слот sockMesReady. Похоже, что не получается из java отправить string или принять в qt. Не могу понять в каком месте что не так. Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы можно было отправить сообщение из java в qt?

Comment: лучше предоставьте полный код с указанием IP и порта

Comment: если в Qt не срабатывает сигнал, то может просто нет подключения? и в данном случае не имеет значения, строка там или число. Но что то мне подсказывает, что оно так не заработает - формат строк в java и Qt не обязательно одинаковый при отсылке. я бы делал сериализацию нормальную  (то есть вначале длина 2-4 байта, потом сама строка в сыром виде)